# Create dart model class with a dynamic Map<String, dynamic> json

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this json i wanna create a model in flutter for a rest api call - but i cannot figure out how the model would look like in dart.

```
    {
  "members": [
    {
      "user": "string",
      "joined": 0,
      "metadata": {
        "some value": "XXXX",
        "othervalue": "asddas",
        "somethingelse": "dada"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Main class

My main class looks like this

```
`
import "metadata.dart";

class Queuers {
  String user;
  int joined;
  Metadata metadata;

  Queuers({this.user, this.joined, this.metadata});

  factory Queuers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Queuers(
      user: json['user'],
      joined: json['joined'],
      metadata: json['metadata'] != null
          ? new Metadata.fromJson(json['metadata'])
          : null,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['user'] = this.user;
    data['joined'] = this.joined;
    if (this.metadata != null) {
      data['metadata'] = this.metadata.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
`
```

Metadata class - i trying to parse metadata dynamic data to something else but it fails fails..

```
class Metadata {
  // String additionalProp1;
  // String additionalProp2;
  // String additionalProp3;
  Map<String, dynamic> metadata;

  Metadata({this.metadata});

  factory Metadata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Metadata(
      metadata: json['metadata'],
    );

    // return Metadata(
    //   additionalProp1: json['additionalProp1'],
    //   additionalProp2: json['additionalProp2'],
    //   additionalProp3: json['additionalProp3'],
    // );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['additionalProp1'] = this.additionalProp1;
    data['additionalProp2'] = this.additionalProp2;
    data['additionalProp3'] = this.additionalProp3;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Original code in commented out - im trying to change fromJson method to return a Map of metadata.

Comment: can you add the code where you parse from json to model?

Comment: Thats this code ´  {
  "members": [
    {
      "user": "string",
      "joined": 0,
      "metadata": {
        "some value": "XXXX",
        "othervalue": "asddas",
        "somethingelse": "dada"
      }
    }
  ]
}´

Comment: That's the json code, i was asking about the code where you implement this model. Something like : var temp = Queuers.fromJson(jsonData);

Comment: The code i use is above for this.

Comment: your first part is the json code, your 2nd and 3rd class is the model. I can't see any code that "use" the model. Check the [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes)